# React-Router route component is constructed twice on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component that boots up a timer with `setInterval` in the `componentDidMount` in my component associated with `/testRoute`.

That looks like:

```
componentDidMount() {
        if (this.timer == null) {
            var timerFunction = function() { this.tick() }.bind(this)
            this.timer = setInterval(timerFunction, 500);   
        }
    }
```

I have a balancing line of code to remove the timer when the component 'goes away' (not sure to what extent this lifecycle hook is equivalent to the object dying, e.g. getting deallocated),

```
componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer)
    }
```

The problem is that if I'm on route `/testRoute` and I refresh the browser, `constructor()` is called twice, and so is `componentDidMount`.  At this point, there are two "timers" ticking.  If I navigate to another route, `componentWillUnmount` is called and one of the timers is cleared.  But that still leaves the one.

Is it expected behavior that my component should hit `componentDidMount` twice on page refresh?  And if so, how can I ensure that only one timer is ever setup?

## edit:

-demonstrating this with a skeleton example:

```
function Nav() {    
        return (
            <ul className='nav'>
            <li><Link to='/test'>test</Link></li>
            </ul>
            )
    
}
```

With a single route:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
            <div>
            <Nav />
            <Route path='/test' component={Test} />
            </div>
            </Router>
            )
    }
}
```

And a trivial component:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        console.log("constructor")
    }
    render() {
        return <div>test</div>
    }
}
```

In this code: "constructor" is logged to the console twice on refreshing `/test`.

Comment: Is this component dependent on a parent component in any way?

Comment: Two time call of componentDidMount is not an expected behavior. Probably the way you are using react-router or the way you are rendering the component is not right.

Comment: no.  The route is `<Route exact path='/renderer' component={Renderer} />`.  Renderer renders a canvas element, and a `<Stage />`.  `Stage` is the component that adds the timer in `componentDidMount`.  But both `Renderer` and `Stage` have their constructors/componentDidMount's called twice on refresh.

Comment: i tested this on a trivial component that just renders an empty div, with that basis `<Route..>` code, and `constructor` is called twice.

Comment: This should not happen. Can you update your question with 'Renderer' component. Please update router info and its version also

Comment: @Dev done, added some basic code, which when i run, calls constructor or componentDidMount twice.

Comment: @AlexBollbach react-router v4?

Comment: `"version": "4.1.2"` yes

Comment: @AlexBollbach, it should work. I don't see any problem. I tried with React 15.6.1 and "react-router": "^4.1.2", "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2". Its works fine.

Comment: well since i've been looking at this for days and have gotten no where, maybe you can checkout the source.  if not, thats fine.  
https://github.com/AlexanderBollbach/webApp2

Comment: @Prakashsharma thanks for letting me know to look elsewhere and not react-router.  it turns out it was a webpack issue, because i had written my html template wrong, and it was including the app bundle twice in my `/dist` build folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue which my component mounted twice. In my case, I make a request in componentDidMount which called twice. I render some of Route by taking from server by async call (App.ROUTES), and some as static (routeInfo.insideDashboard). And the static components mount twice.

```
<Dashboard specialMenu={this.state.menu}>
    <Switch>
        {routeInfo.insideDashboard.map(route =>
            <Route exact key={route.path} path={route.path} component={Auth(route.component)}/>)}
        {App.ROUTES.map(route => <Route key={route.urlPath} exact path={"/" + route.urlPath} 
            component={Auth(asyncComponent(route.importPath, {title: route.title}))}/>)} 
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
     </Switch>
</Dashboard>
```

I suspect that the reason can be render of static routes (routeInfo.insideDashboard) twice, before other routes come from server and after it. I add a check `routesFromServerTaken` before render Routes which ensures Route (definitions) render only once.

```
<Dashboard specialMenu={this.state.menu}>
    <Switch>
        {routesFromServerTaken ? routeInfo.insideDashboard.map(route =>
            <Route exact key={route.path} path={route.path} component={Auth(route.component)}/>): null}
        {App.ROUTES.map(route => <Route key={route.urlPath} exact path={"/" + route.urlPath} 
            component={Auth(asyncComponent(route.importPath, {title: route.title}))}/>)} 
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
     </Switch>
</Dashboard>
```

This solved my problem, components mount only once now.